# Unable to access JSON property containing hyphens or numbers in the key - Rollup and TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript, import, svelte, rollupjs

I'm trying to load a large JSON file with import. The JSON file contains an object, some keys start with numbers and others have hyphens. The problem is that when I try to access keys that contain hyphens or numbers it returns undefined.

I'm using Rollup to build since I'm using Svelte, I've installed the json() plugin to be able to import, but apparently it has problems parsing the object keys.

I noticed this as I was looping throw the object and the properties with hyphens returned undefined while the ones with a single word worked fine.

This is an example object that can be accessed without any problems:

```json
"accusoft": {
    "changes": [
      "5.0.0"
    ],
    "ligatures": [],
    "search": {
      "terms": []
    },
    "styles": [
      "brands"
    ],
    "unicode": "f369",
    "label": "Accusoft",
    "voted": false,
    "svg": {
      "brands": {
        "last_modified": 1548363722323,
        "raw": "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 640 512\"><path d=\"M322.1 252v-1l-51.2-65.8s-12 1.6-25 15.1c-9 9.3-242.1 239.1-243.4 240.9-7 10 1.6 6.8 15.7 1.7.8 0 114.5-36.6 114.5-36.6.5-.6-.1-.1.6-.6-.4-5.1-.8-26.2-1-27.7-.6-5.2 2.2-6.9 7-8.9l92.6-33.8c.6-.8 88.5-81.7 90.2-83.3zm160.1 120.1c13.3 16.1 20.7 13.3 30.8 9.3 3.2-1.2 115.4-47.6 117.8-48.9 8-4.3-1.7-16.7-7.2-23.4-2.1-2.5-205.1-245.6-207.2-248.3-9.7-12.2-14.3-12.9-38.4-12.8-10.2 0-106.8.5-116.5.6-19.2.1-32.9-.3-19.2 16.9C250 75 476.5 365.2 482.2 372.1zm152.7 1.6c-2.3-.3-24.6-4.7-38-7.2 0 0-115 50.4-117.5 51.6-16 7.3-26.9-3.2-36.7-14.6l-57.1-74c-5.4-.9-60.4-9.6-65.3-9.3-3.1.2-9.6.8-14.4 2.9-4.9 2.1-145.2 52.8-150.2 54.7-5.1 2-11.4 3.6-11.1 7.6.2 2.5 2 2.6 4.6 3.5 2.7.8 300.9 67.6 308 69.1 15.6 3.3 38.5 10.5 53.6 1.7 2.1-1.2 123.8-76.4 125.8-77.8 5.4-4 4.3-6.8-1.7-8.2z\"/></svg>",
        "viewBox": [
          "0",
          "0",
          "640",
          "512"
        ],
        "width": 640,
        "height": 512,
        "path": "M322.1 252v-1l-51.2-65.8s-12 1.6-25 15.1c-9 9.3-242.1 239.1-243.4 240.9-7 10 1.6 6.8 15.7 1.7.8 0 114.5-36.6 114.5-36.6.5-.6-.1-.1.6-.6-.4-5.1-.8-26.2-1-27.7-.6-5.2 2.2-6.9 7-8.9l92.6-33.8c.6-.8 88.5-81.7 90.2-83.3zm160.1 120.1c13.3 16.1 20.7 13.3 30.8 9.3 3.2-1.2 115.4-47.6 117.8-48.9 8-4.3-1.7-16.7-7.2-23.4-2.1-2.5-205.1-245.6-207.2-248.3-9.7-12.2-14.3-12.9-38.4-12.8-10.2 0-106.8.5-116.5.6-19.2.1-32.9-.3-19.2 16.9C250 75 476.5 365.2 482.2 372.1zm152.7 1.6c-2.3-.3-24.6-4.7-38-7.2 0 0-115 50.4-117.5 51.6-16 7.3-26.9-3.2-36.7-14.6l-57.1-74c-5.4-.9-60.4-9.6-65.3-9.3-3.1.2-9.6.8-14.4 2.9-4.9 2.1-145.2 52.8-150.2 54.7-5.1 2-11.4 3.6-11.1 7.6.2 2.5 2 2.6 4.6 3.5 2.7.8 300.9 67.6 308 69.1 15.6 3.3 38.5 10.5 53.6 1.7 2.1-1.2 123.8-76.4 125.8-77.8 5.4-4 4.3-6.8-1.7-8.2z"
      }
    },
    "free": [
      "brands"
    ]
  }
```

And this is an example object that returns undefined when accessed:

```json
"accessible-icon": {
    "changes": [
      "5.0.0"
    ],
    "ligatures": [],
    "search": {
      "terms": [
        "accessibility",
        "handicap",
        "person",
        "wheelchair",
        "wheelchair-alt"
      ]
    },
    "styles": [
      "brands"
    ],
    "unicode": "f368",
    "label": "Accessible Icon",
    "voted": false,
    "svg": {
      "brands": {
        "last_modified": 1546440860962,
        "raw": "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 448 512\"><path d=\"M423.9 255.8L411 413.1c-3.3 40.7-63.9 35.1-60.6-4.9l10-122.5-41.1 2.3c10.1 20.7 15.8 43.9 15.8 68.5 0 41.2-16.1 78.7-42.3 106.5l-39.3-39.3c57.9-63.7 13.1-167.2-74-167.2-25.9 0-49.5 9.9-67.2 26L73 243.2c22-20.7 50.1-35.1 81.4-40.2l75.3-85.7-42.6-24.8-51.6 46c-30 26.8-70.6-18.5-40.5-45.4l68-60.7c9.8-8.8 24.1-10.2 35.5-3.6 0 0 139.3 80.9 139.5 81.1 16.2 10.1 20.7 36 6.1 52.6L285.7 229l106.1-5.9c18.5-1.1 33.6 14.4 32.1 32.7zm-64.9-154c28.1 0 50.9-22.8 50.9-50.9C409.9 22.8 387.1 0 359 0c-28.1 0-50.9 22.8-50.9 50.9 0 28.1 22.8 50.9 50.9 50.9zM179.6 456.5c-80.6 0-127.4-90.6-82.7-156.1l-39.7-39.7C36.4 287 24 320.3 24 356.4c0 130.7 150.7 201.4 251.4 122.5l-39.7-39.7c-16 10.9-35.3 17.3-56.1 17.3z\"/></svg>",
        "viewBox": [
          "0",
          "0",
          "448",
          "512"
        ],
        "width": 448,
        "height": 512,
        "path": "M423.9 255.8L411 413.1c-3.3 40.7-63.9 35.1-60.6-4.9l10-122.5-41.1 2.3c10.1 20.7 15.8 43.9 15.8 68.5 0 41.2-16.1 78.7-42.3 106.5l-39.3-39.3c57.9-63.7 13.1-167.2-74-167.2-25.9 0-49.5 9.9-67.2 26L73 243.2c22-20.7 50.1-35.1 81.4-40.2l75.3-85.7-42.6-24.8-51.6 46c-30 26.8-70.6-18.5-40.5-45.4l68-60.7c9.8-8.8 24.1-10.2 35.5-3.6 0 0 139.3 80.9 139.5 81.1 16.2 10.1 20.7 36 6.1 52.6L285.7 229l106.1-5.9c18.5-1.1 33.6 14.4 32.1 32.7zm-64.9-154c28.1 0 50.9-22.8 50.9-50.9C409.9 22.8 387.1 0 359 0c-28.1 0-50.9 22.8-50.9 50.9 0 28.1 22.8 50.9 50.9 50.9zM179.6 456.5c-80.6 0-127.4-90.6-82.7-156.1l-39.7-39.7C36.4 287 24 320.3 24 356.4c0 130.7 150.7 201.4 251.4 122.5l-39.7-39.7c-16 10.9-35.3 17.3-56.1 17.3z"
      }
    },
    "free": [
      "brands"
    ]
  }
```

I already know that hyphens are treated as operators, so I'm using the required square brackets property access.

This is my TS code:

```js
import * as iconsList from '../../data/fontawesome-5/metadata/icons.json';
export interface IconEntryCollection {[key: string]: IconEntry; }

//Some code goes here

constructor(){
   this.iconEntries = iconsList as IconEntryCollection;
   this.icons = [];
}

//Some code goes here

console.log(this.iconEntries['accessible-icon'])//Prints undefined
```

I don't know if the problems is something I'm doing wrong or its just Rollup not parsing the json correctly.
I'm hoping to add more example code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashes in object keys are not valid js unless handled with kids gloves everywhere.

The Roll-up JSON plugin strips all dashes for this reason, and changes the next word identifier to upper case. Aka accessible-icon -> accessibleIcon

Comment: I've already tried with the new word identifier to upper case and it still doesn't work. I think Rollup is not including them in the compiled file. If console.log the entire imported file it is not in there either.

Comment: All the identifiers are run through this: https://github.com/rollup/plugins/blob/master/packages/pluginutils/src/makeLegalIdentifier.ts

Comment: And this is what build the output. https://github.com/rollup/plugins/blob/master/packages/pluginutils/src/dataToEsm.ts